# Проблема в Android Studio

Tags: java, android

После полной компиляции и установки APK файла на эмулятор, приложение просто не запускается (Экран просто белый), 
В дебагинге каждую секунду появляется такое сообщение:

```
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x14 a=-1} 
W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x10/d=0x14 a=-1} 
W/EGL_emulation: eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented 
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to set EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR on surface 0xdb0d14a0, error=EGL_SUCCESS`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

возможно какая-то вьюшка объявлена, но не инициализирована (например textView). Есть команда на неё и поэтому приложение падает не выдавая ошибки. у меня самого часто так бывает

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решилась путем инициализирования всех переменных.